# Can I list all-level subdirectories in a directory and all files' info (an easy way)?

Tags: unicode, encoding, terminal, directory, subdirectory

I did some research on this, and found that I can use

`ls * -r` to list all files, first level folders.
`file */*` to list all first level files info, including their encodings.
`find . -type f` to list all files in all level folders (without any file info).

So I'm thinking about how to combine the 2nd and the 3rd to list all-level folder files and their info (most important to me: their encodings)

Any idea would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To show all files (`find...`) and what `file` command can reveal about them, try:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} +
```

- this uses `find` command's ability to run further commands upon its results , when using `-exec` option
- syntax `-exec yourcommand {} +`. The `+` makes it so it runs one instance of your command `file`, but passing the findings as arguments, similar to your original `file *...`